# Remove generated fields javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xml

I have a problem removing fields with a js function. First, I generate this as much a as I have entries in the database table:

```
function queryComposant($param) {
    $query = "SELECT nom_" . $param . " FROM " . $param . ";";
    $result = connectdb()->query($query)or die("Err " . $query);
    $resultat = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    echo '<table border = "1" id="table' . $param . '">';

    foreach ($resultat as $value) {

    }

    while ($resultat = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

        echo '<tr>'
        . '<form action="' . $param . 'Delete.php"  method="post">';
        $n = "nom_" . $param;
        $nom = $resultat->$n;
        echo '<td>' . $nom . '</td>'
        . '<input id="' . $param . 'delete" type="hidden" name="delete" value="'.$nom.'"    />'
        . '<td><input type="button"  onclick="remove();" value="Supprimer" /></td>'
        . '</form>'
        . '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```

and I'd like to remove the entire `tr` in the table each time I click on the button "Supprimer".

```
function remove(){
    $().live('click',function(){
        var whichtr = $(this).parent().parent();
        whichtr.remove(); 
    });
}
```

what am i doing wrong? I used `$(this).parent().parent();` to go from `button` to `td` and from `td` to `tr` and then try remove it but the function only removes the button.

I also tried this, with no more success:

```
function remove(){
    $().live('click',function(){
        var whichtr = $(this).closest("tr");
        whichtr.remove(); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a handler to bind the click event on "supprimer", as soon as you have had this event directly to the onclick method of the button

so you can write something like that :

```
function remove(){
   var whichtr = $(this).closest("tr");
   whichtr.remove(); 
}
```

(not tested)

I hope it may help

Answer (score 2):

Since inline javascript event handler are considered bad practice, I removed them and made a click event handler in javascript itself.

Assuming this sample html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <form>
        <td></td>
        <input type="hidden" />
        <td>
        <input type="button"  class="remove" value="Supprimer" />            
        </td>
        </form>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <form>
        <td></td>
        <input type="hidden" />
        <td>
        <input type="button"  class="remove" value="Supprimer" />            
        </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The following js will work:

```
$('table').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/320jdapy/)

Comment: your code works fine on the jfiddle you gave, but still removes the button only on my code..but thanks for the answer anyway.still looking , i keep you posted.

Comment: I've found a solution using your code. i give a class name and i include the js code in the onclick(); . Is this what you inteded to say ?

Comment: sorry i cant vote for you reply since my reputation is below 15

Comment: No, I meant that you completely remove the `onClick()`, add the class instead and furthermore add the js code in an external js file. Glad you got it to work nevertheless. Well, you could simply accept my answer (the green tick) instead, since it seems to have solved your problem..

Comment: Thanks for your post, as it's a bad practice to use inline event handler, I think your solution is better than mine I voted up

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
<input type="button"  onclick="remove(this);" value="Supprimer" />
```

Remove method as follow:-

```
function remove(e){
      $(e).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Copied from question:*

Works if I include the js code directly in the generated form:

```
function queryComposant($param) {
    $query = "SELECT nom_" . $param . " FROM " . $param . ";";
    $result = connectdb()->query($query)or die("Err " . $query);
    $resultat = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    echo '<table border = "1" id="table' . $param . '">';

    foreach ($resultat as $value) {
    }

    while ($resultat = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

        echo '<tr>'
        . '<form action="' . $param . 'Delete.php"  method="post">';
        $n = "nom_" . $param;
        $nom = $resultat->$n;
        echo '<td>' . $nom . '</td>'
        . '<input id="' . $param . 'delete" type="hidden" name="delete"       value="'.$nom.'"     />'
        . '<td>'
        . '<input type="button" onclick="$(\'table\').on(\'click\', \'.remove\', function() {'
        . '$(this).closest(\'tr\').remove();});" class="remove" value="Supprimer" />'
        . '</td>'
        . '</form>'
        . '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```